# Detect click outside control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I display TestControl in grid when user clicks on the button:

```
<Grid>
    <myControls:TestControl Panel.ZIndex="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="100" Height="100" />
    <Button "Open Test Control" Click="btnOpen_Click" />
</Grid>
```

How can I hide TestControl when user clicks outside this control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `Grid`:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <myControls:TestControl x:Name="tc" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="100" Height="100" />
    <Button Content="Open Test Control" Click="btnOpen_Click" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

---

```
private void Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (!tc.IsMouseOver)
        tc.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but [LostFocus event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) may be a way to go, given that you set focus to your test control after showing it.

Comment: No, LostFocus event didn't fire. I clicked outside my control